# Which jQuery method should be used to load in a block of markup in this conditional css function?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, responsive-design

I am using WordPress to [load content conditionally](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ConditionalCSS/) depending on the viewport size, but I need to replace the `load()` method with a more appropriate method. You can see how this works in the link above by resizing your browser and watching it load a custom value depending on the browser size.

Example CSS:

```
    body:after { 
        display: none; 

        /* Default */
        content: "Mobile";
    }

    @media (min-width: 35em) {
        body:after {
            content: "Desktop";
        }
    }
```

To be very specific, if the JS can detect that `content: "Mobile"` is active, it will load mobile content. If it detects `content: "Desktop"`, it will load desktop content.

Here's the javascript I'm trying to work with:

```
$(function() {
    var currentSize = "Mobile";
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var size = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ':after').getPropertyValue('content');

        /* Ridiculous thing to deal with inconsistent returning of
        value from query. Some browsers have quotes some don't */
        size = size.replace(/"/g, "");
        size = size.replace(/'/g, "");

        if (size != currentSize) {
            if (size == 'Desktop') {
               $(".content").load('file.php');
               currentSize = 'Desktop';
            }
        }

    }).resize();

}
```

I only just realized the `load()` method isn't right for what I'm trying to do. How do I load a block with custom hooks?

Here is some example code I want to insert into the desktop version to replace the mobile version code:

```
    <div class="item">
        <h2 class="nav-tab">One</h2>
        <?php the_block('One'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2 class="nav-tab">Two</h2>
        <?php the_block('Two'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2 class="nav-tab">Three</h2>
        <?php the_block('Three'); ?>
    </div>
```

As you can see, there are 3 custom hooks that contain more markup and code. I don't know how to properly load this into the javascript so that it will replace the mobile version code.

Comment: I can understand wanting to do something in resize, but devices aren't going to change from mobile to desktop. So if "mobile" and "desktop" are just notional reflections of window size, there should be no need to read `getComputedStyle()` / `getPropertyValue()`, and instead test `$(window).width()` and/or `$(window).height()` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but that part of this script works as intended. :)

Comment: To change the content, either (a) wrap the HTML in a containing div, then use `load()` to reload everything from the first contained `<div>` to the last `</div>`, or (b) wrap blocks one, two and three in their own `<div id="block_one"></div>` (or similar) and do three separate `.load()s`.

Comment: I can't use `load()` because it's trying to pull data from the server whether through a file or url. As far as I can see, it won't allow me to pull a block of content. I don't know how to use `load()` to pull a block of content if it's possible. I'd prefer to load a custom hook or hooks.

Comment: Is this your server, over which you have control, or a public web-service?

Comment: But you have control over what's served - `file.php` contains your code?

Comment: This is why I want to use a custom hook because it comes from the database, not the file itself.

Comment: OK, then you have the means of controlling exactly what's returned in response to a request. Client-side, you can use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [$(selector).load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). The particular content category can be specified by passing `data` argument. Server-side, the PHP will test something like `$._GET('contentID');` and respond accordingly. Providing server-side and client-side scripts are compatible, everything will work - the world is your oyster.

Comment: I looked at all three of those today and have no clue how to make them work because they're all trying to pull this content from either files or URLs. Are you sure that's the right way to go? I don't know how to write this properly.

Comment: If the content isn't to be pulled from files or URLs, then from where?

Comment: From the WordPress mySQL database. Everything in WordPress is stored there.

Comment: But Wordpress is just a set of server-side scripts plus a database, accessed over the web via HTTP requests, in other words URLs! Get it?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I can't just plug a URL into these functions because it'll return everything. How do I specifically pull the data from the database? This is what doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: OK I understand, but that's not a jQuery question. It's Wordpress.

Comment: Haha, back to square one! It's a tag team effort to get this to work. I wasn't sure that `load()` was the right method and I need to understand how to grab a certain bit of content from the database. If you're right, you helped me answer half the question!

Comment: Micah, try searching the Wordpress documentation for "partial views".